# SQLite Getting multiple results with LIMIT 1

Tags: sql, sqlite, limit

I have the following problem.

Part of a task is to determine the visitor(s) with the most money spent between 2000 and 2020.
It just looks like this.

```
SELECT UserEMail FROM Visitor
JOIN Ticket ON Visitor.UserEMail = Ticket.VisitorUserEMail
where Ticket.Date> date('2000-01-01') AND Ticket.Date < date ('2020-12-31')
Group by Ticket.VisitorUserEMail
order by SUM(Price) DESC;
```

Is it possible to output more than one person if both have spent the same amount?

Answer (score 0):

Use `rank()`:

```
SELECT VisitorUserEMail
FROM (SELECT VisitorUserEMail, SUM(PRICE) as sum_price,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(Price) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Ticket t
      WHERE t.Date >= date('2000-01-01') AND Ticket.Date <= date('2021-01-01')
      GROUP BY t.VisitorUserEMail
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  You don't need the `JOIN`, assuming that ticket buyers are actually visitors.  If that assumption is not true, then use the `JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you very much. That helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`CTE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) that returns all the total prices for each email and with `NOT EXISTS` select the rows with the top total price:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT VisitorUserEMail, SUM(Price) SumPrice 
  FROM Ticket 
  WHERE Date >= '2000-01-01' AND Date <= '2020-12-31'
  GROUP BY VisitorUserEMail
)
SELECT c.VisitorUserEMail
FROM cte c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM cte
  WHERE SumPrice > c.SumPrice
)
```

or:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT VisitorUserEMail, SUM(Price) SumPrice 
  FROM Ticket 
  WHERE Date >= '2000-01-01' AND Date <= '2020-12-31'
  GROUP BY VisitorUserEMail
)
SELECT VisitorUserEMail
FROM cte 
WHERE SumPrice = (SELECT MAX(SumPrice) FROM cte)
```

Note that you don't need the function `date()` because the result of `date('2000-01-01')` is `'2000-01-01'`.
Also I think that the conditions in the `WHERE` clause should include the `=`, right?

Comment: Thank you that also helped to understand ctes better.